# generate dataset from RGBIF with null values

Tags: r, dataset

The following code is supposed to, when called generate a valid table for plotting a map based on coordinates, along with other important details.

```
gbif_to_df <- function(sp_names, gbif_data) { 
  myspecies_coords_list <- vector("list", length(sp_names)) 
  names(myspecies_coords_list) <- sp_names
  for (s in sp_names) {
    coords <- gbif_data[[s]]$data[ , c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude", "occurrenceStatus", "institutionCode", "basisOfRecord", "year", "references")] 
    
    myspecies_coords_list[[s]] <- data.frame(species = s, coords)
  }
  lapply(myspecies_coords_list, head)
  as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, myspecies_coords_list), row.names = 1:sum(sapply(myspecies_coords_list, nrow)))
```

based on the following data, where sp_names parameter is the following `(typeof(sp_names)` gives "character" but I'm pretty sure its a list of characters):

```
[1] "Cortinarius  paragaudis"         "Cortinarius  anomalus"           "Cortinarius  albocyaneus"        "Cortinarius  coleoptera"        
 [5] "Cortinarius  valgus"             "Cortinarius  disjungendus"       "Cortinarius  claroplaniusculus"  "Cortinarius  confirmatus"       
 [9] "Cortinarius  saturninus"         "Cortinarius  lucorum"            "Cortinarius  dolabratus"         "Cortinarius  glaphurus"         
[13] "Cortinarius  cinnamoviolaceus"   "Cortinarius  nolaneiformis"      "Cortinarius  uraceonemoralis"    "Cortinarius  bivelus"
```

and this is the second parameter `gbif_data` is imported using `occ_data()` function from `library(rgbif)`:

```
Occ. found [Cortin.. (982), Cortin.. (10006), Cortin.. (110), Cortin.. (306), Cortin.. (450), Cortin.. (201), Cortin.. (16), Cortin.. (8), Cortin.. (1356), Cortin.. (1892), Cortin.. (216), Cortin.. (148), Cortin.. (71), Cortin.. (43),
     Cortin.. (8), Cortin.. (2097), Cortin.. (37), Cortin.. (31), Cortin.. (106), Cortin.. (31), Cortin.. (32), Cortin.. (294), Cortin.. (1239), Cortin.. (767), Cortin.. (127), Cortin.. (11934), Cortin.. (163), Cortin.. (0), Cortin..
     (9605), Cortin.. (1841), Cortin.. (2167)] 
Occ. returned [Cortin.. (982), Cortin.. (10000), Cortin.. (110), Cortin.. (306), Cortin.. (450), Cortin.. (201), Cortin.. (16), Cortin.. (8), Cortin.. (1356), Cortin.. (1892), Cortin.. (216), Cortin.. (148), Cortin.. (71), Cortin.. (43),
     Cortin.. (8), Cortin.. (2097), Cortin.. (37), Cortin.. (31), Cortin.. (106), Cortin.. (31), Cortin.. (32), Cortin.. (294), Cortin.. (1239), Cortin.. (767), Cortin.. (127), Cortin.. (10000), Cortin.. (163), Cortin.. (0), Cortin..
     (9605), Cortin.. (1841), Cortin.. (2167)] 
Args [hasCoordinate=TRUE, occurrenceStatus=PRESENT, limit=10000, offset=0, scientificName=Cortinarius paragaudis,Cortinarius anomalus,Cortinarius albocyaneus,Cortinarius coleoptera,Corti] 
31 requests; First 10 rows of data from Cortinarius  paragaudis

# A tibble: 982 × 161
   key     scientificName decimalLatitude decimalLongitude issues datasetKey publishingOrgKey installationKey hostingOrganizationKey publishingCountry protocol lastCrawled lastParsed crawlId basisOfRecord occurrenceStatus taxonKey kingdomKey
   <chr>   <chr>                    <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>            <chr>           <chr>                  <chr>             <chr>    <chr>       <chr>        <int> <chr>         <chr>               <int>      <int>
 1 417354… Cortinarius p…            60.9             9.21 "cdc,… b124e1e0-… d3978a37-635a-4… 7bdf9f6d-317a-… d3978a37-635a-4ae3-bb… NO                EML      2024-02-13… 2024-02-1…     318 HUMAN_OBSERV… PRESENT          10907776          5
 2 440177… Cortinarius p…            60.9             9.22 "cdc,… b124e1e0-… d3978a37-635a-4… 7bdf9f6d-317a-… d3978a37-635a-4ae3-bb… NO                EML      2024-02-13… 2024-02-1…     318 HUMAN_OBSERV… PRESENT          10907776          5
 3 440132… Cortinarius p…            59.3            14.9  ""     38b4c89f-… b8323864-602a-4… 4346b227-ca68-… 4c415e40-1e21-11de-9e… SE                EML      2024-02-10… 2024-02-1…     430 HUMAN_OBSERV… PRESENT          10907776          5
 4 440142… Cortinarius p…            59.3            14.9  ""     38b4c89f-… b8323864-602a-4… 4346b227-ca68-… 4c415e40-1e21-11de-9e… SE                EML      2024-02-10… 2024-02-1…     430 HUMAN_OBSERV… PRESENT          10907776          5
 5 440136… Cortinarius p…            63.9            20.2  ""     38b4c89f-… b8323864-602a-4… 4346b227-ca68-… 4c415e40-1e21-11de-9e… SE                EML      2024-02-10… 2024-02-1…     430 HUMAN_OBSERV… PRESENT          10907776          5
 6 440386… Cortinarius p…            59.4            14.8  ""     38b4c89f-… b8323864-602a-4… 4346b227-ca68-… 4c415e40-1e21-11de-9e… SE                EML      2024-02-10… 2024-02-1…     430 HUMAN_OBSERV… PRESENT          10907776          5
 7 441500… Cortinarius p…            56.3            15.4  ""     38b4c89f-… b8323864-602a-4… 4346b227-ca68-… 4c415e40-1e21-11de-9e… SE                EML      2024-02-10… 2024-02-1…     430 HUMAN_OBSERV… PRESENT          10907776          5
 8 441491… Cortinarius p…            64.0            19.7  ""     38b4c89f-… b8323864-602a-4… 4346b227-ca68-… 4c415e40-1e21-11de-9e… SE                EML      2024-02-10… 2024-02-1…     430 HUMAN_OBSERV… PRESENT          10907776          5
 9 417362… Cortinarius p…            61.1            10.7  "cdc,… b124e1e0-… d3978a37-635a-4… 7bdf9f6d-317a-… d3978a37-635a-4ae3-bb… NO                EML      2024-02-13… 2024-02-1…     318 HUMAN_OBSERV… PRESENT          10907776          5
10 440465… Cortinarius p…            59.2            10.4  "cdc,… b124e1e0-… d3978a37-635a-4… 7bdf9f6d-317a-… d3978a37-635a-4ae3-bb… NO                EML      2024-02-13… 2024-02-1…     318 HUMAN_OBSERV… PRESENT          10907776          5
# ℹ 972 more rows
# ℹ 143 more variables: phylumKey <int>, classKey <int>, orderKey <int>, familyKey <int>, genusKey <int>, speciesKey <int>, acceptedTaxonKey <int>, acceptedScientificName <chr>, kingdom <chr>, phylum <chr>, order <chr>, family <chr>,
#   genus <chr>, species <chr>, genericName <chr>, specificEpithet <chr>, taxonRank <chr>, taxonomicStatus <chr>, iucnRedListCategory <chr>, coordinateUncertaintyInMeters <dbl>, continent <chr>, stateProvince <chr>, year <int>, month <int>,
#   day <int>, eventDate <chr>, startDayOfYear <int>, endDayOfYear <int>, modified <chr>, lastInterpreted <chr>, license <chr>, isSequenced <lgl>, isInCluster <lgl>, datasetID <chr>, datasetName <chr>, recordedBy <chr>, geodeticDatum <chr>,
#   class <chr>, countryCode <chr>, gbifRegion <chr>, country <chr>, publishedByGbifRegion <chr>, identifier <chr>, habitat <chr>, dynamicProperties <chr>, associatedReferences <chr>, county <chr>, locality <chr>, municipality <chr>,
#   gbifID <chr>, collectionCode <chr>, occurrenceID <chr>, catalogNumber <chr>, institutionCode <chr>, locationID <chr>, rightsHolder <chr>, eventID <chr>, identificationVerificationStatus <chr>, language <chr>, taxonID <chr>,
#   vernacularName <chr>, eventTime <chr>, nomenclaturalStatus <chr>, verbatimEventDate <chr>, verbatimSRS <chr>, verbatimLocality <chr>, parentNameUsageID <chr>, acceptedNameUsageID <chr>, ownerInstitutionCode <chr>, accessRights <chr>, …
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names
>
```

The code seems to generate at best a list filled with 0's. Error points seem to be

```
myspecies_coords_list[[s]] <- data.frame(species = s, coords)
```

where it seems to have a row mismatch problem, something to do with there being null values/rows with lengths of 0.

furthermore,

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, myspecies_coords_list), row.names = 1:sum(sapply(myspecies_coords_list, nrow)))
```

seems to not do its job at all due to the following error:

```
Error in sum(sapply(myspecies_coords_list, nrow)) : 
  invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

I am struggling to get all parts working without another function being compromised. building a sound proof function is seeming quite challenging in this instance. I am a beginner to R.

Comment: My approach how to get all necessary information from GBIF for species occurence(s) is presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77654753/17486894. It may (or not) be  useful.