Obtain all attributes from an rgbif occurrence download
I have downloaded occurrence data using the rgbif package successfully. However, the attributes that are available seem restricted. Specifically, I would like: Habitat, Identification remarks and Occurrence remarks. Is there a way to obtain that information via R?
library(rgbif)
# Request data 
occ_download(pred_and(pred("phylumKey", 35), pred("gadm","ETH")),
             format = "SIMPLE_CSV")

# Check download status using occurrence number,
# see result in console from previous step
occ_download_wait("download occurrence number")

# Load data
df <- occ_download_get("download occurrence number") %>%
  occ_download_import()

Explore data : no attributes for habitat, etc
names(df)
 [1] "gbifID"                           "datasetKey"                       "occurrenceID"                     "kingdom"                         
 [5] "phylum"                           "class"                            "order"                            "family"                          
 [9] "genus"                            "species"                          "infraspecificEpithet"             "taxonRank"                       
[13] "scientificName"                   "verbatimScientificName"           "verbatimScientificNameAuthorship" "countryCode"                     
[17] "locality"                         "stateProvince"                    "occurrenceStatus"                 "individualCount"                 
[21] "publishingOrgKey"                 "decimalLatitude"                  "decimalLongitude"                 "coordinateUncertaintyInMeters"   
[25] "coordinatePrecision"              "elevation"                        "elevationAccuracy"                "depth"                           
[29] "depthAccuracy"                    "eventDate"                        "day"                              "month"                           
[33] "year"                             "taxonKey"                         "speciesKey"                       "basisOfRecord"                   
[37] "institutionCode"                  "collectionCode"                   "catalogNumber"                    "recordNumber"                    
[41] "identifiedBy"                     "dateIdentified"                   "license"                          "rightsHolder"                    
[45] "recordedBy"                       "typeStatus"                       "establishmentMeans"               "lastInterpreted"                 
[49] "mediaType"                        "issue"     


From my experience it returns all fields found on back-end for given query. In dataset downloaded for Chenopodium pumilio for example there are fields: occurrenceRemarks (in 5861 of 15722 records), identificationRemarks (180 of 15722) and habitat (974 records). My GBIF workflow is described https://stackoverflow.com/a/77654753/17486894 - you may find it useful.

I'm still working through your code because it bugs at a couple of points but the downloaded file looks much different from mine (I have a single csv while with your code I get multiple files). I don't understand what is different since the main command is occ_download_get and your call is very similar to mine.

Have modified the answer a bit - at least the error should gone.

The output formats (and fields provided by those formats) are described here: https://techdocs.gbif.org/en/openapi/v1/occurrence#/Occurrence%20download%20formats. And yes, there is a huge difference between DWCA (default) and simpleCVS...

Ah, got it! A simple little option that I missed because the default was used in your code. I followed the tutorials that only supplied SIMPLE_CSV

Do you want to answer the question officially or for me to supply the answer? I don't want to take your credit but I like to close questions as often as possible.

C'man, feel free to add answer and close the question :). I'm glad it helped.

@GrzegorzSapijaszko I'm running into another wall. I've realized that the function occ_download_import() only extracts values from the occurrence table but I would like some attributes from the verbatim table (another .txt file) (e.g. verbatimLatitude). Is there a specific function to pull that out automatically?

I'm not aware of any function from {rgbif} which can read from the verbatim.txt, but you can read it as data frame like df <- read.delim("data/0029245-241126133413365/verbatim.txt") and then left join it by gbifID.

Well, that was obvious! I should have thought of that. Thanks!

Thanks to the comment by @Grzegorz Sapijaszko I was able to resolve the issue. I had requested SIMPLE_CSV as the file format for download (as in many of the tutorials I had followed). However, the number of attributes available from a SIMPLE_CSV is limited. To get all available data, use DWCA as a method of download. This downloads data into multiple separate text files into a folder.
Here is the updated code (also a simple tweak to make it more easily reproducible by saving the download number into a res object and changed the phylum to one with fewer species to speed up the example).
library(rgbif)
# Request data 
res<-occ_download(pred_and(pred("phylumKey", 13), pred("gadm","ETH")),
             format = "DWCA")#!!!! change SIMPLE_CSV to DWCA

# Check download status using occurrence number,
# see result in console from previous step
occ_download_wait(res)

# Load data
df <- occ_download_get(res) %>%
  occ_download_import()

